# Limit Simple Features Plot based on geojson Polygon

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'd like to limit a plot based on a polygon defined in geojson, so that it only shows the area shaded blue [here](https://www.birmingham.gov.uk/info/20076/pollution/1763/a_clean_air_zone_for_birmingham/2).

i.e. just plot the features inside and including the ring road.

The geojson is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2in2nxlwnoauyix/Birmingham%20CAZ%202020.GeoJSON).

It would also be great to add a buffer around the edge to include the ring road.

My code to draw all the features (unlimited by the geojson is below).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)

bounding_box <- getbb("Birmingham", featuretype = "city")

streets <- bounding_box %>%
  opq()%>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", 
                  value = c("motorway", "trunk", "primary", "secondary", "tertiary")) %>%
  osmdata_sf()

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = streets$osm_lines,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "grey",
          size = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-1.933, -1.869),
       ylim = c(52.46,  52.496),
       expand = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume in the following that the object `streets` has already been defined by running the first few lines of the code in the question. The next step is then to read the polygon using `read_sf()` from the `sf` package. The next line converts to a more suitable coordinate system (OSGB 1936 / British National Grid) because adding a buffer in meters is not possible in lon/lat-coordinates. A buffer of 40 meters is added using `st_buffer()` and finally the coordinates are transformed back to WGS84:

```
library(sf)
area <- read_sf("~/Birmingham CAZ 2020.GeoJSON") %>%
        st_transform(27700) %>%
        st_buffer(units::set_units(40, m)) %>%
        st_transform(4326)
```

Of course, you need to adapt the path to where you have actually stored the file. Then I use `st_intersection()` to extract the part of `streets$osm_lines` that lies inside the polygon:

```
streets_area <- st_intersection(poly, streets$osm_lines)
```

And finally I produce the plot using the code from your question. Note that I have added a layer with the polygon in the second line in order to demonstrate that the streets indeed lie inside the polygon:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = area) +
  geom_sf(data = streets_area,
          inherit.aes = FALSE,
          color = "grey",
          size = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    legend.position = "none"
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-1.933, -1.869),
       ylim = c(52.46,  52.496),
       expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Stibu, this works.  I've now realised the area is slightly too small as it chops off the ring road, so will handcraft a slightly bigger one in uMap.

Comment: @Chris Adding a buffer around your polygon could easily be done in R. If you edit your question such that it requests that a buffer be added around the polygon, I could include that in my answer.